# jquery: bind multiple events, then unbind a couple of them? is this right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

bind multiple events, then unbind a couple of them? is this right?

basically when you hover over the element, the background color changes, then changes back when you hover out of the element, but when you click the element i want to disable the hover effect and change the background color to a different color so the user knows that they clicked on it. what's the best way to do this? thanks!

```
$('.tellmereplies').bind({click: function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#0099ff', 'color':'#fff'})
    $('.tellmereplies').unbind('mouseover','mouseout')
},mouseover: function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#fbca54', 'color':'#fff'})
},mouseout: function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#E4E4E4', 'color':'#c0c0c3'})
}
});
```

Comment: Don't forget that [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) will simplify both binding and unbinding, since it binds both mouseenter and mouseleave in one method.

Comment: If you want to toggle the `mouseover` and `mouseout`, it would be nice to just toggle it by adding/removing `class` and not unbind events.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at jquery's [event namespacing](http://loft.bocoup.com/john-resig-advanced-jquery/). I think that is probably going to be useful to you.

```
$("#div1").bind("event_name.namespace1");
$("#div1").bind("some_other_event.namespace1");
$("#div1").bind("event_name.namespace2");
$("div1").unbind(".namespace1");
```

Comment: after looking into it a bit more, thank you for this. It's exactly what will help me grow in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$('.tellmereplies').bind("click", function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#0099ff', 'color':'#fff'})
    $(this).unbind('mouseover mouseout')
}).bind("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#fbca54', 'color':'#fff'})
}).bind("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).animate({'backgroundColor':'#E4E4E4', 'color':'#c0c0c3'})
});
```

Comment: awesome, i forgot to mention that after I click it and it unbinds mouseover and mouseout, that if the user clicks it again it will toggle those back on and bind them again, i tried a few things but couldn't get it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this mainly in CSS. You can create the hover effects for your links using the :hover pseudo-class

```
.tellmereplies:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0099ff;
}
```

Then when the user clicks on the link, add another class value to the link and override the hover effects for the link.

```
$('.tellmereplies').addClass('tellmereplies-clicked');

.tellmereplies-clicked {
    /* new colors */
}

.tellmereplies-clicked:hover {
    /* new colors */
}
```

Comment: that doesn't animate though, in my code i have it fading from color to color, it makes it look a lot smoother and nicer.

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't spotted that. You could use CSS transitions to achieve that effect. Would only work in Safari and Chrome for now, but a nice bit of progressive enhancement.